# Global imports in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Is there an Xcode (5) project setting where I can specify which .h files to automatically import in all files?

Or do I need to put the import statement manually everywhere?

Comment: You could just add your imports that are to be included to the `.pch` file for that target

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import .h files in your project's `.pch` file to be included project-wide. The `.pch` file is usually located in the "Supporting Files" directory and will be named something like "YourAppName-Prefix.pch".

Comment: I knew there was a way. Thanks.

Comment: I used to it like this in an Xcode 5 / iOS 7 environment as well... Now with iOS 8, I notice that the **_AppName_-prefix.pch** file is not generated any more, what's the proper way to globally import now?